# .NET Assembly corrupting at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, corruption

We have a product with a number of installations (different sites within the same company) that is rarely experiencing an installation failure.

What we see, after this occurs, is that one of our DLLs has corrupted. The DLL is the right size, but the file contents are null - literally 450KB of null.

To the product, this is standard project referenced library.

I'm not aware of any mechanism with the .NET framework that would try to write to that file, or truncate it.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: What method are you using to install the product? Do you have any logging in the installation procedure? It sounds like the space has been reserved for the file but the actual data was not copied to it.

Comment: Product is installed using InstallShield Limited. I don't think this is installer related though - they seem to run fine, until they need to restart the server or service. That's when the problem appears. It's almost line the file space  reallocated during run-time. Unless the customer is reinstalling and not telling us...

Comment: Ah, it was the "experiencing an installation failure" that made me think of that. Is your product being installed to "\Program Files` or similar, or to somewhere like "\Windows"? If the latter, I can imagine some Windows automatic repair mechanism messing things up. Ooh - just thought - have they checked their disks for corruption?

Comment: Does [Why do files end up being filled entirely with null bytes after replication using DFSR?](http://serverfault.com/questions/679322/why-do-files-end-up-being-filled-entirely-with-null-bytes-after-replication-usin) ring any bells?

Comment: Software is installed to Program Files, no dice there. I put a request in to check on any reinstalls that may be occurring. edit - I'll ask about DFSR, but it seems unlikely. Each installation keeps its own configuration not only for our software, but several other vendors software as well.